# Who is the author of The Flowers of Aulit Prison?

Tags: the-flowers-of-aulit-prison

That's pretty much it.  I really enjoyed reading it as part of an anthology.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Changing the question after it has an answer is generally frowned upon.  Also, requests for outside resources are off-topic, without even considering the issue of piracy.

Comment: Yes. If you want to discuss this story (and how to *legally* get a copy) with @NKCampbell, you can always use [chat] – you should have enough reputation. Altering the question could end up invalidating answers or leading to Q&A chats, though, and that is best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer: Nancy Kress

[image]